# Python SUMPRODUCT of elements in nested list

Tags: python

I have two nested lists:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[2,4,2]]
b = [[5,5,5],[1,1,1]]
```

I want to multiply and SUMPRODUCT each group of elements to get

```
c = [[30],[8]]
```

Which result from `= [[1*5+2*5+3*5],[2*1,4*1,2*1]]`

I´ve tried doing:

```py
c = sum(x * y for x, y in zip(a, b))
```

But I get "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'"

Is there a simple list comprehension way to do this avoiding for loops?

Comment: You should instead first try to write it with for loops and add some `print`s to understand what is going on. When you have understood it, you can rewrite it in a more concise way.

Comment: Umm... How is 1*2+2*5+3*5 = 30? Order of operatations says "multiply, then add" so it should be 2+10+15=27, right?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do matrix multiplication.  If so, you might want to just start using multi-dimensional arrays in `numpy`.

Comment: You probably mean 1*5 as first, right? It would be...Which result from = [[1*5+2*5+3*5],[2*1,4*1,2*1]]

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE** Use [`math.sumprod()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.sumprod) in Python 3.12+, roughly equivalent to

`sum(itertools.starmap(operator.mul, zip(vec1, vec2, strict=True)))`

See @knia's solution.

---

Implement the `dotproduct` [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) (removed in Python 3.11):

```
import operator


def dotproduct(vec1, vec2):
    return sum(map(operator.mul, vec1, vec2))
```

Code

```
a = [[1,2,3], [2,4,2]] 
b = [[5,5,5], [1,1,1]]

[[dotproduct(x, y)] for x, y in zip(a, b)]
# [[30], [8]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Numpy solution

```
import numpy as np

c = map(lambda x: sum(np.prod((np.array(x)), axis=0)), zip(a,b))

[30, 8]
```

If you need to produce `[[30], [8]]` then

```
c = map(lambda x: [sum(np.prod((np.array(x)), axis=0))], zip(a,b))
```

Comment: That's not the desired result. And if it were, you could also do `(np.array(a) * b).sum(1).tolist()`, no? (I'm not sure. I'm a numpy noob)

Comment: To get the exact result you would have to reshape the array.  `(np.array(a)*np.array(b)).sum(1).reshape((2,1)).tolist()`

Comment: or you can just put brackets around the `sum` function and it will produce `[[30], [8]]`

Answer (score 1):

**Without numpy**

A solution with list comprehension, maybe will this:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[2,4,2]]
b = [[5,5,5],[1,1,1]]

c = [[sum(map(lambda m: reduce(lambda h,i: h * i, m), n))] for n in [zip(x, y) for x, y in zip(a, b)]]
```

And show me:

```
[[30], [8]]
```

Another more clean solution is a simple for loop

```
a = [[1,2,3],[2,4,2]]
b = [[5,5,5],[1,1,1]]

c = []

for x, y in zip(a, b):
    temp = []
    for m, n in zip(x,y):
        temp.append(m * n)
    c.append([sum(temp)])
```

Result:

```
[[30], [8]]
```

Sorry for not readable variable names, I recommend the simple `for` in this cases

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.12 introduced [math.sumprod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.sumprod):

```py
>>> import math
>>> a = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 2]]
>>> b = [[5, 5, 5], [1, 1, 1]]

>>> [math.sumprod(x, y) for x, y in zip(a, b)]
[30, 8]
```

In older versions, I think

```py
>>> [sum(e0 * e1 for e0, e1 in zip(row_a, row_b))
     for row_a, row_b in zip(a, b)]
[30, 8]
```

reads more easily than the `map`/`reduce` solutions suggested elsewhere.

If you really need extra inner lists like `[[30], [8]]` (why?), then add an extra `[]` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a nested list comprehension but it would be complicated.  Here it is one step at a time.

```
a = [[1,2,3],[2,4,2]]
b = [[5,5,5],[1,1,1]]
result1 = [[x*y for x, y in zip(r1, r2)] for r1, r2 in zip(a, b)]
c = [[sum(r)] for r in result1]

c
[[30], [8]]
```

Comment: Your code disagrees with your text, it's a nested list comprehension.

Comment: Correction made.  Thanks @Stefan.

Comment: Good point @Stefan.  I can't figure out how to do it without nesting!